# Login Control Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, event-handling, password-hash

I used membership API to create users and hashed the password in database. Because of the hashed password the Login control cannot authenticate as I'm now unable to set up the login control to convert the user password entered to "Hash" value before referencing the database. 
I have tried exploring the Login control "Logging_in" event handler but I seem very confused on how to use it.

I will appreciate any help

Comment: If you're using the Membership API, you (or the Login Control) should be calling Membership.ValidateUser, passing the username and cleartext password.  It is the responsibility of the MembershipProvider to do any hashing / encryption that is needed.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I tried the Membership.ValidateUser but Login failed. I guess I may be missing a class snippet that will complete the Login process